# Probability from a given discrete CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have found a video on YouTube stating

| X | F(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.32 |
| 3 | 0.67 |
| 4 | 0.9 |
| 5 | 1 |

When we want to figure out P(a ≤X ≤b) , we take F(4) - F(2), according to the video.. However, in my lecture it was as follows: Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) has the property of right continuity, and I suppose that we should take

(the formula was there like that)

$$
P(a ≤X ≤b) = F(b) - F(a) + f(a)
$$

because of the point probability (we need to include 4), and this would give us 0.81.

Can you maybe tell who is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you post a link to the video? Without any context it is difficult to know what to make of your statements.

Comment: $P(2\le X\le 4)=P(1<X\le4)=F(4)-F(1).$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively we have
\begin{align*}
P(2 \leq X \leq 4) & = P(X = 2) + P(X = 3) + P(X = 4)  \\
& =  F_{X}(2) - F_{X}(2^-) + F_{X}(3) - F_{X}(3^-) + F_{X}(4) - F_{X}(4^-) \\
& = 0.12 + 0.35 + 0.23 \\
& = 0.7
\end{align*}
With the formula
\begin{align*}
P(2 \leq X \leq 4) & = F_X(4) - F_X(2) + P(X = 2) \\
& = F_X(4) - F_X(2) + F_X (2) - F_X(2^{-}) \\
& = F_{X}(4) - F_X(2^-) \\
& = 0.9 - 0.2 \\
& = 0.7
\end{align*}
Could you check your calculations, because in both cases it gives the same result